# How to use #include in big projects?

Tags: c++, include

Should I #include everything I need in every header/cpp file? I am working on a 2d game engine atm (for practice mostly) and in reviewing my code I realise that I repeat string and vector in almost every file. Is this an issue and how do I deal with it?

I've always had the opinion that every class or module you write should stand on it's own two legs, so to speak. I really enjoy generic programming (I'm including my own script language in the engine, with my own drafted script engine) but I also realise it could cause a lot of overhead and confusion.

Comment: If there are proper `#ifdef`s, including a header multiple times should not cause any problem. Also you're right in #2.

Comment: if you want to create a header file that is all the common includes and include that instead you could but I wouldn't go any further than that. And I would caution against putting too much in that file and/or including that file across the board.

Comment: If you are familiar with generic programming, you may feel the "#include" in c/c++ inflexible and unhandy. What you need to do is to get familiar with c/c++, and think in c/c++.  :)

Comment: @ciphor: Thinking in C and thinking in C++ are two very different things.

Comment: I've thought about using char arrays instead of string in the more low level parts of the engine. It's quite easy to parse, and tbh I don't even think I'd have to parse it since I'm reading all the text from files anyway. How would this affect performance if at all? I'm more comfortable using strings anyway and the char arrays I would have to delete manually, so I'd only do it if it would greatly improve the performance, mind you it's a rogue type dungeon crawler 2d-game.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standard #include convention for C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691079/is-there-a-standard-include-convention-for-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would stick to including `<string>` and `<vector>` only where necessary.

As for making sure individual header files stand on their own, I like how the Google C++ Style Guide deals with [include order](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Names_and_Order_of_Includes#Names_and_Order_of_Includes).  Basically, always list the corresponding `foo.hpp` include before all other includes in `foo.cpp`.  That way, we know that `foo.hpp` won't expect something to be included before it and fail if it isn't there.

Comment: For once, I quite like the guideline provided by Google, that's a change :p

Answer (score 2):

It's not an issue. You should include, in every file, the absolute minimum dependencies- no more, but no less.